# Swipe up to load with LoaderManager/CursorAdapter, ContentProvider and Service

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I try to follow Virgil Dobjanschis' Designpattern in my app. so far everything is OK, I can couple the ContentProvider, IntentService with the ListView.

additionally I use SwipeRefreshLayout to let user swipe down to manually load new data from my REST service (and store in local DB).

but I also want to let user swipe up to load some old data from the REST service. I got stuck with this point: how to use the ListView with LoaderManager to swipe up to load?

is it possible to do this in `onLoadFinished()` method by checking the result from cursor? or use SwipeRefreshLayout to listen to both Swipeup and SwipeDown events? for now I only find it is possible to listen to the swipe down event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably what is called an "infinite"/"lazy load" scrolling list. When user reaches the end of your list you should retrieve more items from the api. [here](http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-infinitely-scrolling-list-android/)  is an example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the REST call when the user at the end of the list.

There are 2 ways to understand if the user is at the end.

One way is to use `ScrollView` callbacks. They are not specifically written for `ListView`.

The other way is to use your `Adapter`'s `getView` function. When the user scroll down, `getView` is called one by one with the position of the item. When the position is the last item you can start the `IntentService` to do its thing.

You have to make sure that you start the IntentService only once. You can have a flag for that.

Comment: Thanks Tasomaniac too! this approach with getView() to start IntentService sounds another good alternative.

Comment: I actually wrote the 2 alternatives. Although the library is retired, this is a great library from commonsguy and it uses getView approach. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless